# How to write mathematica code for Newton's Forward Difference Formula?

Tags: numerics

I want to write the Newton's Forward Difference Formula in mathematica:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NewtonsForwardDifferenceFormula.html

I know there many functions to interpolate data in mathematica, but I really need Newton's Forward Difference Formula.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The $\Delta$ operator in *Mathematica* is `DifferenceDelta`.  Here is Newton's formula:

```
Sum[Binomial[a, n] DifferenceDelta[f[x], {x, n}], {n, 0, Infinity}]
```

Examples:

```
Block[{a = 1, f = Exp},
 Sum[Binomial[a, n] DifferenceDelta[f[x], {x, n}], {n, 0, Infinity}]
 ]
(*  E^(1 + x)  *)

Block[{a = 2, f = TrigToExp@*Sin},
  Sum[Binomial[a, n] DifferenceDelta[f[x], {x, n}], {n, 0, Infinity}]
  ] // FullSimplify
(*  Sin[2 + x]  *)
```

Comment: Dear Michael, many thanks for your response, suppose now you have the following data: {{0., 1.}, {0.1, 1.10517}, {0.2, 1.2214}, {0.3, 1.34986}, {0.4, 
  1.49182}, {0.5, 1.64872}, {0.6, 1.82212}, {0.7, 2.01375}, {0.8, 
  2.22554}, {0.9, 2.4596}, {1., 2.71828}}, how can we find the f(x) which fit the data using Newton forward formula?

Comment: @user62716 The formula you cite is an infinite series, but it sounds like you might want http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NewtonsDividedDifferenceInterpolationFormula.html

Comment: Yes Michael, I cited the link in my question, can you help to sort this....thanks

Comment: @user62716 Don't you need an infinite number of data points to do an infinite sum?  I suppose you might want to truncate the sum and just compute a finite partial sum?  Please clarify.

Comment: Dear Michael, yes please it is not infinite sum, just finite sum for the data: {{0., 1.}, {0.1, 1.10517}, {0.2, 1.2214}, {0.3, 1.34986}, {0.4, 1.49182}, {0.5, 1.64872}, {0.6, 1.82212}, {0.7, 2.01375}, {0.8, 2.22554}, {0.9, 2.4596}, {1., 2.71828}}